# Draw a Cyclic State Machine with xypic

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I want to draw the following diagram :

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=0.45in]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{xy}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
 \[\xymatrix{&&&&& n+1 \ar[r]^{\sigma} & \dots \ar@{..}[dd]\\
0 \ar[r]_{\sigma} & 1 \ar[r]_{\sigma} & 2 \ar[r]_{\sigma}  \cdots &  n-1     \ar[r]_{\sigma} & n \ar[ru]^{\sigma} & &\\
&&&&&   n+m-1\ar[lu]^{\sigma}  & \ar[l]^{\sigma}\dots 
}\]
\caption{Cyclic State Machine}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This produces :
[image]

Which is not like I want. How can I draw my desired figure ?

Comment: In what, precisely, the figure you obtain doesn't satisfy you?

Comment: The arrow between 'n+m-1' and 'n' should start from 'n',the position of sigma at right side of 'n+m-1' should middle on the arrow and finally the whole arrow will be  bold.

Comment: although it's possible to adjust the positioning of the node text, it's rather tedious and non-obvious how to do so.  that isn't the way xy-pic is designed.  you might be better off using a different tool.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved my problem  :

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
 \usepackage[margin=0.45in]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{xy}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
 \[\xymatrix{&&&&& n+1 \ar[rr]^{\sigma} && \ar@{..}[dd]\\
0 \ar[r]_{\sigma} & 1 \ar[r]_{\sigma} & 2 \ar[r]_{\sigma}  \cdots &  n-1     \ar[r]_{\sigma} & n \ar[ru]^{\sigma} & &\\
&&&&&   **[r]n+m-1\ar[lu]^{\sigma}  & &\ar[l]^{\sigma}
}\]
\caption{Cyclic State Machine}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Produces :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a TikZ solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
\node (0) at (0,0) {0};
\node[right=of 0] (1) {1};
\draw[->,>=stealth] (0) -- node[auto, swap] {$\sigma$} (1);
\node[right=of 1] (2) {2};
\draw[->,>=stealth] (1) -- node[auto, swap] {$\sigma$} (2);
\node[right=of 2] (dots) {$\dots$};
\draw[->,>=stealth] (2) -- node[auto, swap] {$\sigma$} (dots);
\node[right=of dots] (predn) {$n-1$};
\draw[->,>=stealth] (dots) -- node[auto, swap] {$\sigma$} (predn);
\node[right=of predn] (n) {$n$};
\draw[->,>=stealth] (predn) -- node[auto, swap] {$\sigma$} (n);
\node[above right=5 of n] (sucn) {$n+1$};
\draw[->,>=stealth] (n) -- node[auto] {$\sigma$} (sucn.south west);
\node[below right=5 of n] (nm) {$n+m-1$};
\draw[<-,>=stealth] (n) -- node[auto, swap] {$\sigma$} (nm.north west);
\node[right=of nm] (offbot) {};
\draw[<-,>=stealth] (nm) -- node[auto, swap] {$\sigma$} (offbot);
\node at (offbot |- sucn) (offtop) {};
\draw[->,>=stealth] (sucn) -- node[auto] {$\sigma$} (offtop);
\draw[dotted,line width=1,shorten <=5, shorten >=5] (offbot) -- (offtop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Some explanatory comments.

- The `positioning` library is loaded so that nodes can be positioned relative to each other.
- The `>=stealth` key sets the style of the arrow tips.
- The `auto` key puts the σ labels a "nice" distance away from the arrows; without this they'd be on top of the arrows.
- The `swap` key puts the σ labels on the other side of the arrow, where appropriate.
- The `shorten >` and `shorten <` keys make a given line a bit shorter at both of its ends.
- The `x |- y` construction positions a new node at the horizontal position of node `x` and the vertical position of node `y`.
- The things in parentheses like `(0)`,`(predn)`, `(nm)` etc are just names, for referring to nodes.